# localtime() is off by about 460,000 years on RTL8710

Tags: c, embedded, localtime

I'm using an RTL8710 (running [rustl8710](https://github.com/lupyuen/rustl8710), but that's irrelevant as far as this question goes, since all code I'm talking about is C code). The RTL8710 has proprietary libraries for some parts of the system, including `localtime`.

However, `localtime` seems to be off by about 460,000 years when using it like this (taken from [the included NTP implementation](https://github.com/lupyuen/rustl8710/blob/master/component/common/network/sntp/sntp.c#L182)):

```
long current_sec = 1543067026;
struct tm current_tm = *(localtime(&current_sec));
```

This returns the following struct:

```
{tm_sec = 51, 
 tm_min = 36, 
 tm_hour = 15, 
 tm_mday = 25, 
 tm_mon = 8, 
 tm_year = -458682, 
 tm_wday = 2, 
 tm_yday = 267, 
 tm_isdst = -1515870811}
```

Obviously that's incorrect, it should be something close to 24 Nov 2018 13:52:04 GMT. It's not random though, because the time always seems to differ by around 2 hours and some minutes.

The only other noteworthy thing here is that the code uses the default system headers `time.h` and `string.h` (which would be from Ubuntu 18.10, 64bit in my case).

I have no idea what stdlib library RealTek is really using, but judging by debugging info (`newlib/libc/time/lcltime.c`), I'd guess that it's a (modified?) version of newlib.

Comment: So is it off by 460K years or by 2 hours?

Comment: `localtime(const time_t *timer)` expects a `time_t *`, not necessarily a `long *`.  Use `time_t current_sec`.  If that is not close to a solution, you need to post a [MCVE].

Comment: @stackptr full date is off by 460K years, but time is correct within give or take two hours.

Comment: This code is literally pulled from the SDK provided by Realtek, so I'd expect it to work, but I'll make the suggested modifications and report back with the results. The minimal example is just adding a few headers and wrapping it in a `main {}`, I'll edit that into the question.

Comment: Check also endianness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code is using the wrong type which leads to undefined behavior.<sup>1</sup>

```
// long current_sec = 1543067026;
time_t current_sec = 1543067026;
struct tm current_tm = *(localtime(&current_sec));
```

Better code would test the `localtime()` return value before de-referencing it.

```
struct tm *p = localtime(&current_sec);
if (p) {
  struct tm current_tm = *p;
  ...
```

---

<sup>1</sup>  The wrong type width is evidenced by following.

```
int main() {
  long current_sec = 1543067026;
  struct tm current_tm = { .tm_sec = 51, .tm_min = 36, .tm_hour = 15, //
      .tm_mday = 25, .tm_mon = 8, .tm_year = -458682, //
      .tm_wday = 2, .tm_yday = 267, .tm_isdst = -1515870811 };

  time_t t = mktime(&current_tm);
  printf("%16lx\n%16llx\n", current_sec, (unsigned long long) t);
}
```

Output

```
        5bf95592
fffff2d55bf9a9f3
        ^^^^
```

Many bits lines up.  I suspect the upper bit difference was due to junk bits being referenced by `local_time()` and lower bit difference due to extreme calculation, OP non-synchronized posting of code and purported output, or a difference between my and OP's standard library.  Although `time_t` is zone-less, my and OP's timezone difference contributes to `locatime()/mktime()` differences.

Comment: Yup, this is it. The SDK implementation is just broken. Thanks! (for anyone else that ran into the same issue: you need to change `long update_sec, ...` in `component/common/network/sntp/sntp.c` to `time_t update_sec, ...`. Same for both 3.5a and 4.0b of the SDK)